# Shopify Webhooks: Is there a way to determine whether or not an order came from Shopify POS?

Tags: api, shopify, webhooks

I'm receiving a Webhook for every order that has been maid, but I do not know if it came from POS or from the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the order, and there is indeed a property known as the source of the order. That will tell you where the order originated from. Some Apps generate orders so their source will be a number. POS is pos. You should have no trouble figuring out the source from the attribute in the order.

In GraphQL parlance, you look for the app { name } and for example you'd see something "Draft Order" or "POS". In RestAPI is it probably still just source or source_name.